# What is the supercurrent operator in superconductivity Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity

For a U(1) symmetric Hamiltonian, the current operator can be derived simply by taking the time derivative of the density operator. I wonder how can one obtain a supercurrent operator for U(1) broken Hamiltonian like Bogoliubov de Gennes Hamiltonian? I am only asking about the continuum limit.